# How do I link external libraries to msvc cl compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, visual-studio-2019

today I was trying to link my external SDL2 library to my project to compile with cl.exe, but my program cannot find SDL2.lib and SDL2main.lib and while I trying to include any files, compiler cannot see them. Here is my bat file:

```
@echo off
if not defined DevEnvDir (
    call vcvarsall x64
)
REM call vcvarsall x64

set LIB_VCPKG="F:\Env\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib"
set MLIB_VCPKG="F:\Env\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\manual-link"
set INC_VCPKG="F:\Env\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include"

set CommonCompileFlags=-MD -nologo -fp:fast -EHa -Od -WX- -W4 -Oi -GR- -Gm- -GS -wd4100 -FC -Z7 -I %INC_VCPKG%
set CommonLinkFlags=/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /LIBPATH:%LIB_VCPKG% /VERBOSE:LIB 

if not exist ..\build mkdir ..\build
pushd ..\build

cl ..\code\main.cpp SDL2.lib SDL2main.lib %CommonCompileFlags% /link %CommonLinkFlags%
popd
```

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Add the library directory (directories) to your link path.  Also why are you using a BAT file with MSVS ?  Better options are (a) the IDE; (b) MSBuild; (c) CMake.

Comment: I'm trying to use this method because I am really used to nvim. Ok, I'll try this

Comment: Thank you, adding to link path helped me